# I want the code of previous version of my Django app. How can I get it? I tried git reset --hard but it's not working. It's showing email not found s

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

I deleted the requirements.txt file and again created a new requirements.txt file using pip freeze > requirements.txt And after deploying, it is showing an application error. So I rolled back to the previous version. But I am not able to get the code of that previous version. I tried with the "git reset --hard eeb02c91" command. But it's not working. It's showing "HEAD is now at eeb02c9 Email not registered error added". Someone, please help me to get the code of the previous version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I revert a Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: you can checkout to any of the previous commit. Do `git checkout <commit_id>`